# What am I? (Answer may be superfluous)

Tags: riddle

I start with a fight, or a chance to relax,
And end with a cut, and am but you what.
In between I am quite average,
But overall you hope I am never required.

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A thought is you are a

> **spare**

I start with a fight, or a chance to relax,

> start with a fight - *spar*, or a chance to relax - *spa*,

And end with a cut, and am but you what.

> end with a cut - *pare*, and am but you what : I am but you *are*.

In between I am quite average,

> *par*

But overall you hope I am never required.

> something you keep as a *spare* like a tyre.

Title: Answer may be superfluous

> it may not be needed.

Comment: Correct - that was fast.  Wasn't sure if the bit in the title was going to make it too easy, but needed the characters...

Comment: The title was extra help - and I like clues there. I think found the meaning from the average clue, but your puzzle is a cut above the norm with the density of wordplay. (Also I've asked one with a similar answer!)