# A Puzzle That Reveals More

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> To start, a source of winter fun.
>   To end, where journeys have begun.
>   To link them, there's an evil one.
>   That's even less. Congrats! You're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, a source of winter fun.

> ski

To end, where journeys have begun.

> pier

To link them, there's an evil one.

> imp

That's even less. Congrats! You're done.

> skimpier

Title: A Puzzle That Reveals More

> I hope this answer suits.

Comment: Open question: who posed this question style on Jan 31 2018?

Comment: Let me repeat: congrats! You’re done!

Comment: I think it was @[Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566/riley) who created these types of questions :)

Comment: Historically: [What am I? (Answer may be superfluous)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59943/what-am-i-answer-may-be-superfluous)